# mysql account on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, macos

I was trying to install MySQL 5.6.17 on Mac OS X. On the instruction, it says

> MySQL installation requires a Mac OS X user account named `mysql'. A
>   user account with this name should exist by default on Mac OS X 10.2 and up.

However, I cannot find this account on my Mac. From System Preference -> Users & Groups, I can only see two accounts, namely my admin account and a guest account.

Is the mysql account hidden somewhere? If so, do I need to log in as mysql account before I install mysql? If there is not such an account, do I need to create one myself? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed MySQL at `/usr/local/mysql-XXX`

Check this [documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/macosx-installation.html)

If you installed using `Homebrew`, open Terminal and type -

```
/usr/local/var/mysql
```

That's how it worked for me -

[image]

Yes, 'usr' is hidden for me. Just in case you can use a Terminal command to reveal the hidden files in OS X by making a change to the default behavior of Finder -

`defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`

**UPDATE -**

I also tested using `type -a mysql` on Terminal.

`type -a` is an equivalent of tclsh built-in command where in OS X bash shell. If MySQL is found, it will show :

```
mysql is /usr/local/bin/mysql
```

If not found, it will show:

```
-bash: type: mysql: not found
```

By default , MySQL is not installed in Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Maybe I did not make myself clear. What I really meant is, is the an account named "mysql" on Mac OS X by default? Is that really required to install mysql under this account as described in the instruction. I have tried to install mysql following the instruction, apart from the requirement of being under the "mysql" account. The installation went through fine, but when I run the mysql_install_db program to set up the initial MySQL grant tables, there were errors. I am not sure whether it is because MySQL was not installed under the account "mysql".